# Why apt on debian is showing package version different than command version

Tags: debian, ubuntu-14.04, apt, packages

I was automating some packages requirements with `ansible` and wanted to freeze their version and I found out I am not sure which version is being used by the system.

The debian `apt-get` commands give a different value than the installed command invoked itself.

```
$ python -V
Python 2.7.6
$ dpkg -s python | grep Version
Version: 2.7.5-5ubuntu3
$ apt-cache policy python | grep Installed
  Installed: 2.7.5-5ubuntu3
$ which python
/usr/bin/python
$ echo $PATH
/home/<MY_USERNAME>/.gvm/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

I don't think there's any `$PATH` issue like getting a different `python` command from stuff like `anaconda` (infact that's not installed in the system). The `$PATH` environment variable seems ok.

I can not get why that 2.7.6 / 2.7.5 mismatch?

My OS/distribution version:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
```

Answer (score 0):

`python2.7` executable is actually in `python2.7-minimal` package, and `python` just has (or sets) the symlink that points to the executable. python package does not necessarily have the same version as it is built from different source code package (python-defaults).

Comment: Sorry I am not getting what's the relationship between packages `python-defaults` and `python`, when you say "packages" you mean `.deb` packages or just a general definition for a "source code package"? Here they use "source package" https://packages.debian.org/source/jessie/python-defaults and I find a bit confusing getting a clear picture of the graph of dependency relationships